# Clear ALL autocommands

Tags: autocmd

I have many autocommands in my vimrc. Some of them do have the augroup wrapping to make them not duplicate when re-sourcing the vimrc, but many do not.

Rather than try to wrap all of them at this point, I figured that for my vimrc sourcing bind

```
nnoremap <Leader>L :so $MYVIMRC<CR>:runtime! after/plugin/*.vim<CR>:runtime! after/ftplugin/*.vim<CR>
```

that i should just have it do something similar to treating the entire vimrc as a global augroup and clear that before sourcing the scripts again. I think that I cannot literally do this, because only autocommand-commands should be inside of an augroup, and nested augroups probably are not a thing...

Can this be done? I'm hoping for a feature that just does this, rather than having to programmatically find all set autocommands to clear them one at a time.

Comment: just `autocmd!` .. but no guarantees it doesn't break something somewhere

Comment: I imagine you could add a group to your non-`augroup`'d `autocmd`'s. [However is it best to use a self clearing `augroup`](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/14.html). Use something like `:vimgrep /autocmd/ $MYVIMRC` to find `autocmd` in your `vimrc` file. Use `:cnext`/`:cprev` to jump between locations. See `:h quickfix` and `:h :vimgrep`.

Answer (score 5):

`autocmd!` at the top of .vimrc.

[From the docs:](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/autocmd.html)

> When your .vimrc file is sourced twice, the autocommands will appear twice.
>   To avoid this, put this command in your .vimrc file, before defining
>   autocommands:

```
:autocmd!    " Remove ALL autocommands for the current group.
```

> If you don't want to remove all autocommands, you can instead use a variable
>   to ensure that Vim includes the autocommands only once:

```
:if !exists("autocommands_loaded")
:  let autocommands_loaded = 1
:  au ...
:endif
```

Note: That's from the 7.4 docs. [The 8.0 docs](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/autocmd.txt.html#autocmd-define) omit `autocmd!` in favor of groups:

> :autocmd adds to the list of autocommands regardless of whether they are
>   already present.  When your .vimrc file is sourced twice, the autocommands
>   will appear twice.  To avoid this, define your autocommands in a group, so
>   that you can easily clear them:

```
    augroup vimrc
      autocmd!      " Remove all vimrc autocommands
      au BufNewFile,BufRead *.html so <sfile>:h/html.vim
    augroup END
```

> If you don't want to remove all autocommands, you can instead use a variable
>   to ensure that Vim includes the autocommands only once:

```
    :if !exists("autocommands_loaded")
    :  let autocommands_loaded = 1
    :  au ...
    :endif
```